# Multilang URL subdomains in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, multilingual

Currently i have multi-language setup on my system with no url change. so www.test.com can be English or Spanish or whatever. The user changes the language from the footer.

But  i am thinking maybe it is better to have separate sub-domains for each language like fr.test.com or fr.photos.test.com, etc. Then maybe even add localization like fr-fr.test.com or fr-fr.photos.test.com, etc.

1) Any benefit to add subdomains like above instead of doing what i am already doing?
2) If yes, then how to configure codeignitor to do it for language and localization?

Currently i have a language lookup table which the system uses to output to the user to change the language.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better not to make many subdomains (from SEO perspective every subdomain will be as different website) and use something like website.net/fr-fr/category/subcategory or something like Microsoft uses:

- In English:
  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324767/
- In German:
  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324767/de-DE